# how to make ImageView is behind the button in android xml

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a button and animation with ImageView in main.xml.
problems arise if the application is started button is covered by the ImageView.

how to make ImageView is behind the button?

thank you. .
this is my code:

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/summer">
<Button
android:id="@+id/soal111"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:layout_x="207dp"
android:layout_y="41dp"
android:background="@drawable/primarykey"
android:text=" "
android:textSize="8dp" />
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_x="119dp"
android:layout_y="29dp"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:src="@drawable/awan1" />
```

Comment: Please provide the main.xml .....

Comment: you can  frame layout for that !!

Comment: provide your xml here.So it will easy to ans here,Afterall we do not understand the specific problem belongs to the xml

Comment: first thing first AbsoluteLayout  class is deprecated.use relative layout for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></ImageView>
    <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use FrameLayout. When I was creating applications with a camer view, I used FrameLayout, and I could put on view what I wanted. See [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_frame-layout/).

Answer (score 0):

//put your Image view first

```
 <AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/summer">

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="119dp"
        android:layout_y="29dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/awan1" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/soal111"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:layout_x="207dp"
android:layout_y="41dp"
android:background="@drawable/primarykey"
android:text=" "
android:textSize="8dp" />
```

//remove the android:layout_x & y in both imageview and button.